# Sort spills to tempdb but estimated rows equals to actual rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, tempdb, sorting, cardinality-estimates

On a SQL Server 2016 SP2 with max memory set to 25GB we have a query that executes about 80 times in a minute. The query spills about 4000 pages to tempdb. This causes for a lot of IO on the disk of tempdb.

When you take a look at the [query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rk3qJ9dQE) (simplied query) you'll see that the number of estimated rows is equal to the number of actual rows but still spills occur. So out-of-date statistics can't be the cause of the problem.

I did some testing and following query spills to Tempdb:

```
select id --uniqueidentifier
from SortProblem
where [status] ='A'
order by SequenceNumber asc
option (maxdop 1)
```

But if I select a different column no spills occur:

```
select startdate --datetime
from SortProblem
where [status] ='A'
order by SequenceNumber asc 
option (maxdop 1)
```

So I tried to 'enlarge' the size of the id column:

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar(512),id)
from SortProblem
where [status] ='A'
order by SequenceNumber asc 
option (maxdop 1)
```

Then also no spilling occurs.

Why is the uniqueidentifier spilling to tempdb and a datatime column not?
When I delete about 20000 records then also no spilling happens when I select the id column.

With following script you can reproduce the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE SortProblem
  (
     id             UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
     startdate      DATETIME,
     sequencenumber BIGINT,
     status         VARCHAR(50),
     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(id)
  )

SET nocount ON;

WITH nums(num)
     AS (SELECT TOP 103000 ROW_NUMBER()
                             OVER (
                               ORDER BY 1/0)
         FROM   sys.all_objects o1,
                sys.all_objects o2)
INSERT INTO SortProblem
SELECT newid(),
       DATEADD(millisecond, num, GETDATE()),
       num,
       CASE
         WHEN num <= 100000 THEN 'A'
         WHEN num <= 101000 THEN 'B'
         WHEN num <= 102000 THEN 'C'
         WHEN num <= 103000 THEN 'D'
       END
FROM   nums

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Status]
  ON [dbo].[SortProblem]([status] ASC)
  INCLUDE ([sequencenumber])
```

Comment: Relates to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/268006

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Enable trace flag 7470.

[FIX: Sort operator spills to tempdb in SQL Server 2012 or SQL Server 2014 when estimated number of rows and row size are correct](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3088480/fix-sort-operator-spills-to-tempdb-in-sql-server-2012-or-sql-server-20)

As I wrote in answer to [Query Plan question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/211365/1192):

> This trace flag corrects an oversight in the calculation. It is quite safe to use, and in my opinion ought to be on by default. The change is protected by a trace flag simply to avoid unexpected plan changes.

Comment: It appears this does not apply to 2019, what might be the causes or workaround when row count and data size estimates are both good? [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/268006)

Comment: @crokusek This answer applies specifically to sorts. Your linked question appears to be different (hash table exceeding estimated size).